# How do you clear a single entry from a ruby on rails session?

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-2

In ruby on rails when doing `session[:foo] = nil` it leaves an entry named `:foo` in the session object. How can you get rid of that single entry from the session object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually there is a way to get delete a value from the session. Like RichH said the session variable is a CGI::Session instance. When enter something like `session[:foo]` it is actually looking that symbol up in a `@data` instance variable in the session object. That data variable is a hash.

**EDIT:** There is a data instance variable in the CGI::Session class. If you go to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI/Session.html) and look at the source code for the `[]=` method you'll see that there is a `@data` member.

So to delete `session[:foo]` all you have to do is access that `@data` variable from inside the session

```
   session.data[:foo]
```

Now to delete it:

```
   session.data.delete :foo
```

Once you do this the there should be no more foo in your session variable.

Comment: Is that portable accross all of the session stores? It looks a little intimate as the data attribute isn't mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I discovered it by using debugger and inspecting the session variable. I was able to find a little support for my answer though, http://tinyurl.com/cp7ntm, check out the last method where they assign session_data = @_session.data. That's the most I could find on it

Comment: I just updated my answer with a much better source for some documentation on the subject.

Comment: That's just the ActiveRecord store - if you look at the cookie store, memcache store, etc they don't have this attr_reader - http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/31ce92f7b5784bc5b6a441e88cd734c7b8b1c58f/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb

Comment: The way I understand it is that the CGI::Session:CookieStore is an extension of the CGI::Session class. So CookieStore would inherit everything in CGI::Session. When we modify the Session class (by adding @data to it) we inherit all those changes into the extensions that follow it (CookieStore)

Comment: @data isn't in the base Session class it's in the active record session store - that's the source you pointed to. The memcached session doesn't use @data, it uses an @cache to store the session contents. ActiveRecord does something different to. This is implementation specific.

Comment: Ok @data may not be in the rdoc for CGI::Session but if you take a look at the actual code for the '[]=' method, http://tinyurl.com/djoltc, you'll see that a @data instance variable is created or written to. So for certain session stores Rails will overwrite the @data variable.

Answer (score 81):

It looks like the **simplest version works**.  All stores (Cookie, File, ActiveRecord, ...) use `AbstractStore::SessionHash` as the object that contains the data, the different stores provide only the means to load and save the `AbstractStore::SessionHash` instances.

`AbstractStore::SessionHash` inherits from `Hash`, so this defers to the `Hash#delete` method:

```
session.delete(:key_to_delete)
```

Comment: Looks like they changed the behaviour. This didn't work in Rails 2.3, as far as I remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the Session is a Ruby [CGI::Session](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CGI/Session.html) and not a Hash, calling delete will actually delete session. Delete takes no parameters - this is my you're getting the "wrong number of arguments (1 or 0)" message when you try what hyuan suggests.

The generally accepted way to clear a session entry is with session[:foo] = nil as you suggest. It is far from ideal, but statements like session[:foo].nil? will behave as expected.

I really wish it behaved like a normal Hash ... but it doesn't.